# Java: EOFException in networking

Tags: java, networking, io, eofexception

I am new to networking and I am getting an EOFException when I am trying to run the **MyClient.java**.

**MyServer.java**

```
public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                OutputStream os =socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write("Hello networking");

                bw.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyClient.java**

```
public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4321);
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            System.out.println(dis.readUTF());

            dis.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not connect");
        } catch (UTFDataFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("if the bytes do not represent a valid modified UTF-8 encoding of a string");
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.err.println("if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get **if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes** for the error and the error seems to arise from the **dis.readUTF()** call.

Could someone help me understand what am I missing? I am trying just trying to read what the server writes to the client when it gets connected, that is **Hello networking**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your server code
you should use DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String str) to write to socket if you want to read it with the DataInputStream.